# How make changes on vue project in hosting

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, digital-ocean

I have vue project which published on Digital Ocean. The main problem is when i make some changes on FileZilla it is not affect on website. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is not *an issue* per-se. This is just the way how modern web development works. Vue.js (but also Nuxt) is using a bundler right now (Webpack, Vite are the most common), hence to go to production it needs to be bundled each time you push something to it.

If you upload something via FTP or SSH and edit some source code, a bundle step will be **required** in order to get any changes on the actual webapp.

Backend languages may not need that, for example you could SSH into a server and change some `.php` file, if you F5 the page it will be updated in real time. But this is not how frontend JS code works, it needs to be optimised.

Another thing, sending code via SSH/FTP is not really a good workflow because it is not easily trackable, no version-controlled, will not trigger any build flags in case of an error etc...
The best approach is to have a git repo + some build step included in some CI.
A common platform for it is [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/), you connect a Github repo, you tell which command to use to **build** the project and each time you push some code, it may do some checks/tests/optimizations/etc... via [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) before being released automatically to production (updated on your webapp).

This workflow have a lot of benefits as one may tell but is also de-facto, the official/regular approach for modern Web development on the frontend.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I have to change a little things in vue. For that i wanna edit it from ftp. If you know how can i show my changes on site. What commands or something else i have to do?

Comment: @Deranged_23 The setup that I explained can be done in 5min on Netlify. Otherwise, if you want to stick to FTP, you will then need to bundle your app as usual with something like `npm run build && npm run start` or alike. Check the scripts part of your `package.json` to find out if this is accurate.

Comment: @Deranged_23 Otherwise, a git-flow based is totally fine if you remove a semi-colon `;`, it's not really the quantity that matters here. FTP is just slow/insecure and have no baked-in tracking/versioning + list of other things listed above.

Comment: I'm new at vue. And it is my friends project on backend i added some features and we need to show this features on front. The site is published on digital ocean. Where can i use `npm run build && npm run start` in digitalocean?

Comment: The backend is mixed with the frontend on the same VPS instance? If it's on DigitalOcean, you'll need to SSH into the server. Then, it depends of your setup. @Deranged_23