# I deployed, I deleted, I got this error while deploying again Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: vue.js, deployment, server

I deployed Vue.js project in server, and I wanted to change it, I deleted this project. Again I deployed but I got this error **Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token '<'.** It gave this error even though there was no change in my code what should I do?

Comment: Where did you deployed? What do you mean you deleted the project? Do you have more error logs?

Comment: I deployed it to my own hosting then I deleted the file to make changes I am getting this error there is no other error

Comment: I may recommend this kind of flow rather: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71844156/8816585